# How to use customised SDK of Android to develop Applications using Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

As i am a newbie ,Please accept my mistakes. 
I successfully build Android from AOSP for one of my device.
Now if i want to write applications for my device ,How to set Environment in Eclipse?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install ADT plugin for eclipse and redirect it to your SDK:

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location.

**Upd.** To install plugin go Help -> Install New Software..., press Add and add this path: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I did the process but eclipse is giving error that selected sdk is not proper.

Comment: Is there any details, why?

Comment: I am not taking standard sdk form android site.I build it from Android source.

Comment: Then please guide me via some documents or sites

Comment: Sorry, have no experience with AOSP.